# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de una celda de un datatable con Angular y PrimeNG?

Tags: angular, primeng

**Tengo una columna que se llama "estado" y quiero que cuando este pasado 8 años se pinte de color rojo , pasado 4 años de color amarillo y dentro de 4 años de color verde .**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-info>
                        
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ info.id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ info.bloque }}</td>
                                <td>{{ info.boveda }}</td>
                                <td>{{ info.difunto }}</td>
                                <td>{{ info.fecha }}</td>
                                <td>{{ info.estado }}</td>
                                <td>{{ info.observacion }}</td>
                                <td>{{ info.relacion }}</td>
                                <td>{{ info.tipo }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución sencilla sería añadir un método al componente que, para cada entrada, secidiera la clase:

```js
  getStatusClass(info: ...) : string {
    if (<tiene menos 4 años>) {
      return "textoVerde";
    } else if (<tiene entre 4 y 8 años>) {
      return "textoAmarillo";
    }
    return "textoRojo";
  }
```

Y esto podrías aplicarlo usando el atributo [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass):

```html
...
<td [ngClass]="getStatusClass(info)">{{ info.estado }}</td>
...
```

Si las condiciones fueran muy sencillas (si tuvieras el número en otro atributo), podrías incluso hacer algo como:

```html
...
<td [ngClass]="{textoRojo: info.estadoAnnos > 8, textoAmarillo: info.estadoAnnos > 4 && info.estadoAnnos <= 8, textoVerde: info.estadoAnnos <= 4}">{{ info.estado }}</td>
...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias , lo estaré probando